# Git dir and work tree in different servers

Tags: git, ssh, web-deployment

I have this enviroment in web developing:

**Server A**

Multiple VMs (each one represents a different project). It's used for deploy.

**Server B**

Hosts every git bare repositories

**Local machines**

Each developer clones the repo, works locally, and push back to Server B bare-repo.

---

The problem is that I need to have working tree in each VM (server A), but with no git directory. And maintain git directory with no working tree in server B.

Each time a someone `git push`es to a repository, the *remote* working tree (in server A) needs to be updated.

---

**What do I want to avoid?**

I don't want a full git directory in my deploy server (Server A) because it has SSD disks and i'd take a lot of (very expensive) space.

---

**My first approach**

My first approach was to use a hook for *post-update* in Server B which basically makes `git archive` to a `.gz` file, and uses `scp` with ssh keys and then extracts it in Server A.

PRO is that it's easy to implement.

CON is that I'll transfer every repository files even if someone modified a single line.

---

Can anyone throw me any idea? Is it possible to set GIT_WORK_TREE to a remote location? I tried via ssh with no success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can checkout working directory to server B and transfer them to VMs using rsync.

Recent git (since 2.3.0 if I understand correctly) supports automatic update of the working tree on server (see option receive.denyCurrentBranch to updateInstead), so the hook only needs to run rsync.

Comment: I finally did a `git checkout` in a /tmp work tree followed by a `rsync` in the post-update hook. Working ok by now..